# c++ - Direct and Copy Constructors

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization

```
class UnusualClass
{
    int a;
    public:
        UnusualClass(int a){std::cout<<"Direct initialization"<<std::endl;}
        UnusualClass(const UnusualClass &n){std::cout<<"Copy initialization"; }
};


int main ()
{
    UnusualClass k1(5);    //Direct initialization
    UnusualClass k2=56;   //Copy initialization
    return 0;
}
```

Why does the compiler print out "Direct initialization" twice? I've done some research and found out that I might be getting copy constructor elision. 
Is it possible to get two different outcomes in these two cases?
Also, when I use `UnusualClass(const UnusualClass &n)=delete` I get an error saying `use of deleted function 'UnusualClass::UnusualClass(const UnusualClass&)`. Why would I get this error if it skips this constructor anyways?

I know I can get two different outcomes by using two constructors `UnusualClass(int a);` and `UnusualClass(double b);` but this trick doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: Why do you expect the second one to use the copy constructor? `56` is `int`, not `UnusualClass`

Comment: It seems that you are confusing [*copy-initialization* syntax](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) for *copy constructor* invocation. *copy-initialization* will only lead to *copy constructor* invocation if argument is a reference to the object of the same class.

Comment: The requirement for provision of the copy-ctor for the second may not be intuitive, but elision isn't *required*. Therefore, it has to be available, at least by declaration, even if it ultimately isn't used. Think of it this way. constructing a *temporary* `UnusualClass` from 56 invokes the direct ctor. Then the copy ctor *would* be invoked create `k2` from the temporary, but with elision, half of that disappears.

Comment: The copy constructor would be used with `UnusualClass k2 = k1;`

Comment: The initialization of k2 is rather 'implicit' instead of 'copy initialization' .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't `copy initialization`:

```
UnusualClass k2=56;   // NOT Copy initialization
                      // for 56 is not of type UnusualClass
```

It will call the constructor:

```
UnusualClass(int a)
```

I think you meant:

```
UnusualClass k1(5);    //Direct initialization
UnusualClass k2{k1};   //Copy initialization
UnusualClass k2 = k1;  //Copy initialization
```

Note the type needed in `copy initialization`.

```
UnusualClass(const UnusualClass &n) // const reference to type UnusualClass
```

It should be the object's type which is `UnusualClass`, not `int`

**UPDATE**

> I get an error saying use of deleted function
>
> ```
> UnusualClass::UnusualClass(const UnusualClass&).
> ```
>
> Why would I get this error if it skips this constructor anyways?

```
UnusualClass::UnusualClass(const UnusualClass&) = delete;
```

means:

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)

> Avoiding implicit generation of the copy constructor.

Thus, you will need to define your own copy constructor.

**UPDATE 2**

Refer more to @songyuanyao's answer for `copy-initialization`

Comment: The reason behind the *last* question in the OPs first paragraph is important. Probably worth considering adding to this answer.

Comment: @WhozCraig, updated. thank you for notifying me. also feel free to help me improve my answer.

Comment: I see that, but it till doesn't explain why it is needed. The OP asked why would it be needed if it is never used. In short, why would the compiler complain about it when it doesn't seem to be used in the first place? See my comment in general below the OPs post. songyaunyo's answer actually sites the standard that describes this.

Comment: It *is* called copy-initialization. See the definition - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization

Comment: Thank you @0x499602D2, @WhozCraig, True @songyuanyao had clarified more about `copy-initialization`

Answer (score 2):

[Copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) doesn't mean the copy constructor must be called.

> If T is a class type, and the cv-unqualified version of the type of other is not T or derived from T, or if T is non-class type, but the type of other is a class type, user-defined conversion sequences that can convert from the type of other to T (or to a type derived from T if T is a class type and a conversion function is available) are examined and the best one is selected through overload resolution. The result of the conversion, which is a `prvalue temporary (until C++17)` `prvalue expression (since C++17)` if a converting constructor was used, is then used to direct-initialize the object. `The last step is usually optimized out and the result of the conversion is constructed directly in the memory allocated for the target object, but the appropriate constructor (move or copy) is required to be accessible even though it's not used. (until C++17)`

In the process of this copy initialization (i.e. `UnusualClass k2=56;`), `UnusualClass::UnusualClass(int)` will be selected for converting `int` to `UnusualClass`, so it's called at first. After that the converted `UnusualClass` is used to direct-initialize the object `k2`, so the copy constructor is required conceptually. Before C++17 even [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) happens the copy constructor must be accessible, that's why when you make it `delete` you failed to compile. Since C++17 [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) is guaranteed, and the copy constructor doesn't need to be accessible again.

Answer (score 1):

```
UnusualClass k1(5);    //Direct initialization
UnusualClass k2=56;   //Copy initialization
```

In both of the above cases you are passing a integer, and the only constructor with integer argument is

```
UnusualClass(int a){std::cout<<"Direct initialization"<<std::endl;}
```

Hence the compiler print out "Direct initialization" twice.

Answer (score 1):

The integer 56 is "implicitly" related to your constructor which expects an integer. If you want to disable this behavior, you can set the constructor to explicit.

```
explicit UnusualClass (int a) {...}
```

Disabling means that this will be detected as compiler error:

```
UnusualClass k = 56;
```